# Unable to Load New Flask App in Browser, Old Flask App is Running in Browser

Tags: python, flask

I have made new Flask App, But whenever I try to run it . It is always loading my previous app in the Browser.
I have tried with clearing all the Cached files and data in my Chrome Browser , even working in Incognito Mode is also not working. Tried by writing the simple flask program as below also, even then it is not loading "Testing Flask App" in the browser.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Testing Flask App"

app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: which address did you use? http://localhost:5000 or real address?

Comment: Local host 5000

Answer (score 0):

Try this and change port and hostname as per need:

`app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)`

Comment: Not Working this too

Comment: If you change the port, then also it will the result is the same. Have you stopped the previously running application.

Comment: Yes, the previous one is stopped

Comment: I tried opening in another browser, Changed the IDE to pycharm also.. But even then, it is loading the old main.py file

Comment: If stopped then, hoe it is possible to see the previously run result.

Comment: set FLASK_ENV=development
python app.py
To run the application using the above commands

Comment: have you tried with another browser (Firefox, IE, etc)

Comment: do one thing, that deletes your older application or change the project dir localtion

Comment: Yes.. Tried with different browser.. Used Ctrl+Alt+M to stop the code from both projects.. That seems working Now.. Ctrl+C didn't seem work to stop there.. It always showed Code is running..

Comment: Thank you so much Akshay for your help !!